# Is the verb "close" in "It is recommended that you close all other applications" fixed and does not change regardless of the subject?

Tags: verb-forms

[image]

There is a sentence in the picture as below.

> It is recommended that **you close** all other applications before continuing.

I wonder what happens to the verb “close” if I change “you” into “the user”.
Does the verb change into “closes” or remain as “close”?
To ask one more, is the sentence below also right?

> It is recommended that you will close all other applications before continuing.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the 'subjunctive'?

Comment: In the present tense, the verb recommend is followed by another verb without the third person s. I suggest he do some reading about this. Suggest also works like this.

Comment: The simple answer is maybe. "Recommend" licenses both subjunctive and non-subjunctive complements. With verbs other than "be", and with subjects other than 3rd person, the subjunctive and the non-subjunctive have the same form, so it's impossible to tell whether "close" is a 2nd person present tense verb, or a plain (infinitival) form. If the subject is changed to 3rd person things become clearer: "It is recommended that the user close ..." (subjunctive) ~ "It is recommended that the user closes ..." (non-subjunctive). The subjunctive is considered the more formal construction.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much for the precise and sophisticated answer. I already once read about subjunctive but I didn't know it could apply for the passive form "recommend".

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the comment. The example sentence helped a lot. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remains  unchanged.

After verbs like *suggest*, *request* and *recommend*, it is common to use the base form of the verb in the "that" clause.

(Historically this was a form of the verb known as the *subjunctive*; but in modern English, this form is indistinguishable from the base form (infinitive) for every single verb in the language. I think it is unhelpful to bring in a special name, and prefer to say that you use the base form in this construction.)

Your suggestion with "will" is understandable, but not idiomatic. I don't think any native speaker would say it. 
Some people use the ordinary present here ("I recommend that he closes the application") but the standard literary form is with the base form of the verb .

Comment: Thank you for clearing up! Very helpful. Have a nice day.